# Using hiera to include modules in example42/apache

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm trying to set up a puppet configuration for work (open source version), and my goal is to create a sort of standard class that most of our servers could just use with a simple hiera_include in the manifest.

I'm trying some apache puppet modules for that, the one from puppetlabs seems to support a lot of things but isn't really great to use from hiera, and generate configuration a little too far from what we are used to.

The one from example42 on the other hand let you use your own templates, which is great. But I still can't figure out how to enable modules with that. The doc says

`apache::module { 'proxy':
  templatefile => 'site/apache/module/proxy.conf.erb',
}`

How do I convert that for hiera ?
Is it even possible ? Don't really need the templatefile though, just looking for a way to say "those modules are enabled" in a yaml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, need to use apache::module_hash for that. Not really said in the doc, just showed at one point. Works for everything, there is also a vhost_hash, dotconf_hash ...
Pretty cool !